# how to adjusting already built ML predictive model

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

How can I continue machine learning model after predicting results?

What I mean by that is that I built a model for my 1 million records dataset, this model took around 1 day to get built.

I extracted the model results using Python and now I have a (function) that I can feed it with my features and it gives me a prediction results

but with time my dataset has become 1.5 million records.

I do not want to redo the whole thing all over again from scratch.

Is there any way I continue of top of thf first model I built ( the one with 1 million records) so the new model take less time to adjust it based on the new 0.5 million records compare to re building everything from scratch for 1.5 million records.

P.S. I am asking for all algorithms, if there is anyway to do this for any algorithm that would be good to know which ones are these

Comment: Did you save your model as a .pickle file when you first trained your model ?

Comment: Just train the model you are serving on the new data.

Comment: This gave me second hand anxiety. Depending on what algorithm and implementation you are using, you can save your model periodically just in case something happens during execution that halts the model. But what model is taking a full 24hrs to do just a million rows?